# Speedup drawing transparent images

Tags: c++, gdi+

I need to draw image and make part of this image transparent. I write such code:

```
graphics.SetClip(&nonTransparentRegion);
graphics.DrawImage(pImage, dstRect, srcRect, Gdiplus::UnitPixel);

Gdiplus::ColorMatrix colorMatrix;
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
      colorMatrix.m[i][j] = Gdiplus::REAL(i == j);
colorMatrix.m[3][3] = 0.5;
Gdiplus::ImageAttributes imageAttr;
imageAttr.SetColorMatrix(&colorMatrix);

graphics.SetClip(&transparentRegion);
graphics.DrawImage(pImage, dstRect, srcRect, Gdiplus::UnitPixel, &imageAttr);
```

It's works fine, but it's too slow. I tried to use Bitmap.lockBits and changed alpha channel directly for image, but it's slower. What else can I try?

Comment: Usually rendering transparency is slower but there are a couple of ways to do it: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/66909/Rendering-fast-with-GDI-What-to-do-and-what-not-to